# SASS variable in shorthand properties comples with no space

Tags: css, sass

When using SASS variables inside shorthand-properties in SASS, like this:

```
$variable : 40px
margin : 0 auto -$variable auto;
```

it compiles to CSS like this:

```
margin : 0 auto-40px auto
```

This, of course, yields an error. Is there a way to make the SASS compile as

```
margin : 0 auto -40px auto
```

instead? In other words, how can I make sure there is a space before the variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply change your code to this:

```
margin : 0 auto (-$variable) auto;
```

This avoids SASS interpreting `auto -$variable` as the difference between "auto" and 40 pixels (`auto-40px`).

Per the [SASS Guidelines](https://sass-guidelin.es/#calculations):

> **Top-level numeric calculations should always be wrapped in parentheses**. Not only does this requirement dramatically improve readability, it also prevents some edge cases by forcing Sass to evaluate the contents of the parentheses.